# Returning Different object within WCF method - Not a throw

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, object

I was wondering if i can create a method to return a different object in the catch using the WCF client. I wanted to format a reference type with all the exception details and return it through the WCF client. Here is the code I am trying to achieve.

```
[OperationContract]
PendingAccountDto createAccount(AccountActivationDto account);
```

My implementation of the Interface

```
public PendingAccountDto createAccount(AccountActivationDto account)
        {
            try
            {
                DatabaseHelper.CheckForDatabaseAndCreate();
                AccountDto newAccount = new PendingAccountDto(account);
                response = DatabaseHelper.CreatePendingAccount(newAccount);
                ActivationEmailer.SendEmail(newAccount);
                PendingAccountDto pendingAccount = (PendingAccountDto)newAccount;
                return pendingAccount;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorMessageDto error = ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex);
                return error;
            }
        }
```

Now in the catch I want to return an ErrorMessageDto object but the method defines a return type of PendingAccountDto. I want the wcf client to return the ErrorMessageDto through the client if a catch is triggered but, I cant do this because the return type is expecting a PendingAccountDto. I have looked into FaultCOntracts but every tutorial shows it as a throw and I want a return so I can view the object through the client. Any ideas? Generics on return types dont work with WCF methods. 
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Application exits when i try and set

```
pendingAccount.Error = ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex);

       PendingAccountDto pendingAccount = new PendingAccountDto();
        pendingAccount.Error = ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex);
        response.FailedTransaction(ex);
        return pendingAccount;
```

Comment: 1 word.. inheritance. :). or you can make a class which has a success/failure object along with the "normal" results...a response object. have the client do checks on the response to determine if things worked out or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking it is possible.

All you need to do is to make the ErrorMessageDTO Object composite/nested within the PendingAccountDTO object and probably also provide an accessor method call GetErrorMessageDTO() for the caller of the API to retrieve it during erroneous scenario.

So your code will do something like;

1. catch the exception
2. create the ErrorMessageDTO object
3. Add the ErrorMessageDTO object to the PendingAccountObject
4. return the PendingAccountObject

Then the caller of your API will have to know that an error has occurred by calling some kind of API. I'm thinking you maybe have an API call "HasSucceed()", where it check and see if the ErrorMessageDTO was populated or not, if it is then returns **False**, Else **True**.

On situation where HasSucceed() reports False, then the caller will do a GetErrorMessageDTO() to retrieve it.

Comment: Hmm ill give that a try and respond back, so basically have my PendingAccountObject contain the ErrorMessageDto as a property.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking.

Comment: Seems the application exits when pendingAccount.Error = ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex); is performed. it wont even get to the return at the end

Comment: I think you might have hit another exception there. Try putting a breakpoint there and stepping through it using visual studio and see what happened.

Comment: I only have one try catch and its in the main method because exceptions bubble up. Strange that the application just exits. I am stepping through and on the response back from ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex); the application stops. I appreciate helping me through this

Comment: I don't have visual studio installed on this machine so I can't try stuff for you :(

Will be good if you can share with me your updated code, I/someone else  might be able to find something.

Comment: I did update my code its up top, I am setting pendingAccount.Error = ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex); and right after that the application exits and doesnt reach the return

Comment: Maybe do some small experiment first. 
Removing the line that is making this to exit and also the response.FailedTransaction to prove that you can return PendingAccount object on error. (Which I think it should be possible...)

Does this line "ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex);" returns you a new ErrorMessageDTO object?

How does your PendingAccountDto object code look like now? How does the new Error property look like, codewise?

Comment: I fixed it, something wrong with setter/getter now is there a way to hide the other datamembers? and only have the Error object display? currently the pendingAccount object is showing every dataMember, I only want the Error object if possible to be shown, do you know a way to hide the other members? Going to upvote you for the help.

Comment: I am going to try IgnoreDataMember and see if i can achieve something like this.

Comment: Hey, since the issue has already been resolved. You might want  open another question for this instead? Because the amount of comments we are writing is getting too long.